# Oracle SQL Column division error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this piece of Oracle SQL that has been giving me problems on and off. I have got it to work one time today and then the next time I tried to run it I was given an SQL command not properly ended. All I'm trying to do is divide one column by itself under the 2 different restraints.

```
SELECT start_end_amt,
    in_out_amt
FROM MYTABLE.MYTABLE,
    (
        SELECT sum(start_end_amt)
        FROM MYTABLE.MYTABLE
        WHERE in_out_amt = 'C'
        ) / (
        SELECT sum(start_end_amt)
        FROM MYTABLE.MYTABLE
        WHERE in_out_amt = 'D'
        ) * 100 AS RATIO
ORDER BY RATIO,
    start_end_amt,
    in_out_amt
```

However, now that I run it this way I am getting an error on the *100 part. It's an SQL command not properly ended. As far as I was aware this was the proper way to write a select query.

My expected outcome is to have a table that returns a percent ratio for each transaction that occurs. The one time it did work it was not outputting a percent either unfortunately.

Comment: Move that math up to the SELECT clause. It's nonsense down there in the FROM clause. Better yet share some sample data and your desired results. I have a feeling this is way of base as it's written.

Comment: Can you give sample data and expected output? I have no idea what this query is trying to do.

Comment: Did that and I'm getting an SQL command not properly ended at the *100

Comment: I already gave my expected output if you could mention a specific part I can give you clarification. The sample data would be something like:

Comment: Does this table have some kind of transaction ID? You need to group on that field and do conditional aggregation.

Comment: @PatrickH already gave my expected output if you could mention a specific part I can give you clarification. The sample data would be a dollar amount in start_end_date like xxx.xx and the only two entries in in_out_amt can only be 'D' or 'C' with D meaning outgoing and C meaning incoming. I want to separate the start_end_date (which is a number xxx.xx) between the ones listed as 'D' and as 'C' and then divide the column with 'D' by the 'C's. Then the multiplication is to turn it into decimal form thereby giving me a ratio. Apologies I had meant to edit before your response

Comment: You mentioned that you need `a percent ratio for each transaction that occurs`. If that is the case, then you need some sort of primary key for each transaction (which is not present at all in your query).

Comment: @PatrickH there is a primary key that is a transaction ID. Would your suggestion still be the same as what you said the first time you asked that? A conditional aggregation?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just simply need to group by a transaction ID and do conditional aggregation. Something like this:

```
select transaction_id,
       sum(case when in_out_amt = 'C' then start_end_amt else 0 end) /
          sum(case when in_out_amt = 'D' then start_end_amt else 0 end) * 100 RATIO
  from MYTABLE.MYTABLE
group by transaction_id
```

Comment: This has a different output from the OP's posted question, but this would solve the problem they have, and provides a good starting point for wherever they want to get to.